# Move FMOIX/FMCOX structures into Internal Table

Tags: structure, abap, sap-erp

I am a newbie to ABAP (3 days experience) and I am currently on a task to write reports using ABAP code. It is like moving some data from a specific SAP database to a Business Intelligence staging area.

So the core difficulty is that some data on the SAP server is in the format of dictionary structures (FMOIX, FMCOX, etc.) and I need to move these data into internal tables during program runtime. I was told that OPENSQL would not work in this case.

If you still do not get what I mean, I can suggest several ways, actually given by my supervisor. First is to use GET event, say

```
GET FMOIX.
    IF FMOIX-zhdlt > From_dat and FMOIX-zhdlt < to_dat.
        Append FMOIX to itab.
    ENDIF.
```

The thing is that I am still not very clear about this GET event. Is it just a event handler thing, or can it loop through data records?

What I googled for more than two days give me something like

```
LOOP at FMOIX.
    MOVE FMOIX to itab.
ENDLOOP.
```

So what are the ways to move transactional structure like FMOIX into internal tables, say the internal table name is ITAB?

Your answer would be greatly appreciated. Though I have time, I am totally new.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your supervisor is suggesting that you use the GET event, it means that your program is (or should be) using a **logical database** - in this case probably FMF or FMF_BCS.

Doing `GET FMOIX` reads a set of fields defined in the logical database (as a *node*). Underneath your GET statement, you can use FMOIX as a structure, e.g. `WRITE FMOIX-field1`. The program will (implicitly, it's not explicity defined in the code like a `LOOP...ENDLOOP` is) loop through all the rows returned according to your selection criteria. You should be able to use `MOVE-CORRESPONDING` to move the contents of each row into a proper structure, and then `APPEND` that structure to your itab.

Quick link on GET in [ABAPDocu](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abapget-.htm)

Note: this answer is a bit of a guess, since I've only used a logical database once, and the documentation is a little thin on the ground compared to the volumes out there about standard `SELECT`s and internal tables.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the web but didn't find much about how to deal with logical database, esp the structure.   So you mean first I need to declare an intermediate structure in the program, besides the FMOIX; then load runtime data from FMOIX into the structure, later append to the itab?

Comment: Yup, that sounds about right. So DATA: ls_fmoix type fmoix, lt_fmoix type table of fmoix (or something like that, I'm not sure of the dictionary types in question). I don't think appending the LDB structure straight to an itab would work (but you could give it a go!)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your internal table in type of that structure such as:

```
data: itab like table of fmoix with header line.
```

And you can use this internal table to fill up wherever you are using your select codes.
Such as:

```
select * from ____
   into corresponding fields of itab 
   where zhdlt gt from_dat
   and   zhdlt lt to_dat.
```

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for but I can tell you creating itab in type of that structure can be filled up with all corresponding datas that coming from your select. You cant loop FMOIX because its not a table, its a structure. So is there any specific reason to hold your datas in structures?

Hope it was helpful.

Talha